# Alias piping into awk

Tags: bash, zsh, alias

I am trying to create an `ll` with `awk` pipe alias. I am trying to escape the apostrophes using the following [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159569/how-to-escape-single-quotes-correctly-creating-an-alias).

```
alias lh= `ll -h | awk {'print  $9, \"-\" ,$5, \"-\", $8, \"-\",$7, $6'}`
```

But it doesn't appear to work.

The resulting console output for `bash` and `zsh` is the same.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print  $9, \"-\" ,$5, \"-\", $8, \"-\",$7, $6}
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: {print  $9, \"-\" ,$5, \"-\", $8, \"-\",$7, $6}
awk: cmd. line:1:             ^ syntax error
```

When entering

```
alias lh= `ll -h | awk {'print  $9, "-" ,$5, "-", $8, "-",$7, $6'}`
```

the output is   meaning empty.

Comment: Is `ll` on your system an alias for `ls -l` or is it something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several syntax issues with your alias definition. However, the first problem is that parsing the output of `ls` [is strongly discouraged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/377345) because code that involves it will ultimately stumble upon files with "non-trivial" characters such as spaces, tabs and newlines. In addition, in particular the output format of the timestamp may change depending on how "old" the file actually is, meaning that you can have more or less space-separated "fields" in the input to `awk` depending on the actual file, or one of the fields changing its meaning (e.g. from year in case of an "old file" to time of the day for a "recent file"). These two aspects are what @steeldriver referred to as the alias being "fragile".

The "obvious" issues are:

1. You have a space behind the `=`. This will actually make the alias `lh` undefined (at least in `bash`).
2. You enclosed the alias definition in backticks (`` ` ``), probably in an attempt to create a "third layer" of quoting. However, backticks are the (albeit now deprecated) syntax for command substitution, i.e. `lh` would contain *the console output of the `ll | awk ...` pipeline* and try to execute *that* as a command.
3. You rely on a command `ll` being either present or at least pre-defined as an alias of `ls -l`. This may or may not be the case.
4. Your `awk` program starts has the single-quotes and the curly braces in the wrong order. The correct syntax is `awk ' { ... } '`.

Note that if this is part of a shell script, you may want to run it through [`shellcheck`](https://www.shellcheck.net), also available as standalone tool on many Linux distributions, to catch many syntax-related errors.

The immediate solution to the problem you experience is indeed the correct quoting and escaping. You could try something like

```
alias lh="ls -lh | awk '{print  \$9, \"-\" ,\$5, \"-\", \$8, \"-\",\$7, \$6}'"
```

where the alias is everything in the `" ... "`, the input to `awk` is explicitly stated as `ls -lh`, the `awk` program is enclosed in single quotes, and the field references inside the `awk` program are protected from premature interpretation as shell positional parameters at "definition-time of the alias" by backslash-escaping (so that `awk` actually sees them as `$9` and not replaced by the 9th positional parameter of the shell instance, which is likely empty).

**However**

- the advice found in [one of the answers to the question you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159572/377345) - defining a function - is a far better way to get out of the "quoting hell" (as mentioned by @ilkkachu), so something like

  ```
  lh() { ls -lh | awk '{print  $9, "-" ,$5, "-", $8, "-",$7, $6}'; }
  ```

  is much cleaner and easier to understand
- I would recommend to avoid parsing `ls` altogether, and propose the following `find`-based alias instead:

  ```
  lh() { find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name ".*" -printf "%f - %s - %TY - %Td %Tb\n"; }
  ```

  which uses the `printf` formatting options of `find` to reliably output the desired file properties. The only drawback is that there is no `-h` option for human-readable sizes.

  The `! -name ".*"` filter is used to emulate the standard behavior of `ls` to ignore hidden files. If you want them listed, you can leave that part out.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an if command for ```%s``` to divide by factors of 8 depending on the size e.g. 8bit = 1byte and so on?

Comment: @zerberus As per [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124295/377345), unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to teach `find` that trick. You could post-process the output and pipe it through `numfmt`, but that would somewhat defeat the purpose of using the `find` command in the first place (i.e. not having to post-process output that may contain unusual characters in the file names).